# Testing Message Passing with Messengers in Android

Tags: android, junit, message

I'm trying to test the IPC functionality in my Android application.

I have a service to which clients can bind and send Message objects via the Messenger API. How do I go about testing this?

I tried using ServiceTestCase, but it appears that whenever I send a message to the Messenger of my Service, either JUnit finishes prematurely (this is supposed to be IPC) and the handleMessage of the Handler is not getting called, or JUnit is not supposed to be used for testing things like this (it should be!).

How can I go about this?

My objective is to test the message passing flow, and of course the work that the Service does.

Thanks!

Comment: Yep. It's because the Instrumentation is not running a Looper. I can start the Looper but I can't stop it correctly. :(